# Tools for managing configuration of multiple web applications

Tags: java, web-applications, configuration

We have several Spring MVC and Metro based applications which communicates with each other. Their settings are currently stored in multiple property files, that are made available to apps via `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. This is not convenient because configuration is scattered and some parts of it is duplicated among servers. Currently we are going to create another webapp which is known to every other app and which keeps this whole configuration and provides an interface that allows to request these properties as key-values pairs. Is there any out-of-the box solution of this kind? Or, probably, is there a better way for solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need hot configuration, or just on startup?
If its just on startup, I would do it by some kind of version control system like svn.
So when app starts, it makes a call to svn to get the latest config.

Comment: Just startup. Thanks for option!